# In magento, when is order refunded?

Tags: certification

I am preparing for magento certification exam. I came across below question,

**1. In magento, when is order refunded?**
a. When items are not fully refunded
b. When total order is greater than 0
c. When there is a item which is invoiced but not refunded.
d. B and C

I am confused. According to me option b is correct. Because, if items are fully refunded still we can refund order. If there is a item which is invoiced and refunded still we can refund order. 
What will be correct answer can anybody help me?